# Call to a method inside a for loop with list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I was wondering whether there is more pythonic way or even if it's acceptable to do it this way.

I want to call to some method inside list comprehension, although i don't need any value to be returned, it's just a setter.

Code:

```
def do_logic(self):
        [self.set_key(j) for i in xrange(2, CONSTANT) if self.lis[i] != 1 for j in xrange(i*2, CONSTANT, i)]
```

In my eyes it doesn't seem like the right way to it, any suggestions?

Comment: Wait, so you're not actually using the list? Just use a for loop.

Comment: For loop is faster.  Perhaps more pythonic would be a **map**.

Comment: @Prune map is *the worst*. Because if you tried to run the code in python3 it wouldn't even perform the calls since in python3 map is lazy. In any case both calling `map` or a list-comprehension are **expressions** and expressions should be as side-effect free as possible, their purpose is *to return a value*. So if you don't have a value to return you should just use the plain statements: i.e. explicit `for`.

Comment: @Bakuriu.  On second thought, I quite agree.  Thanks for the correction.  I was in brainstorming mode, rather than solution mode.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need the list, don't use a list comprehension.  Just use a loop.